# How do I delete spyware from a Mac Notebook?

Tags: macos, malware

I recently watched a lengthy video from a political blog; since then my computer gets a lot of "Oh snap" screens and I lose my web page.  Also when I turn my computer on, multiple windows are open even though I wasn't using them.  Are these signs that someone has hacked my computer with spyware?  And if so, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Sounds like it's time to buy a new Mac :-P

Answer (score 1):

To check for malware, you can install and run some free antivirus/antispyware software. The free versions of antivirus software often have limitations with some not supporting real-time scanning only on-demand scanning, etc., but if you don't want to just wipe everything on the drive and reinstall the operating system and all your applications, etc., you could try eliminating the malware with one or more of the following:

[Avast Free Mac Security](https://www.avast.com/en-us/free-mac-security)

[AVG AntiVirus for Mac](http://www.avg.com/us-en/avg-antivirus-for-mac)

[Avira Free Antivirus for Mac](http://www.avira.com/en/free-antivirus-mac)

[ClamXav](https://www.clamxav.com/)

[Comodo Antivirus for Mac](https://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/antivirus-for-mac.php)

[Norton AntiVirus for Mac](http://us.norton.com/downloads-trial-mac-antivirus) - 30-day free trial

[Panda Antivirus for Mac](http://www.pandasecurity.com/usa/homeusers/solutions/antivirus-for-mac/) - free trial

[Sophos Antivirus for Mac](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-mac-home-edition.aspx)

It is usually not a problem to have more than one antivirus program on a system if no more than one scans in real-time. E.g., if you have one constantly running looking for malware, but the other only runs when you manually start it and initiate a scan, you should be ok. But if you put multiple antivirus programs on a system that will be doing real-time scanning, i.e., checking files when you open or download them, you can have conflicts that can make a system perform terribly slowly or even render it unusable. So if you are going to install free trial versions that do real-time scanning, I'd suggest uninstalling a prior real-time scanning one if it didn't eradicate the malware before trying another one.

I'd recommend keeping antivirus on your Mac notebook and keeping it up-to-date even if you eliminate the current problem. Macs may not be as frequently targeted as Microsoft Windows systems due to having a smaller user base than Microsoft Windows, but they are targeted by malware developers, also.